# Disable Android lock-out (un)feature

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, lock-screens, locked-out, lg, hard-reset

Unfortunately, someone thought is was funny to mash my lock screen buttons (phone fell out of my pocket while sitting on the floor), which required me to sign in via my Google account. Now normally this would be somewhat OK, but I was not connected to WiFi or Data. So I was forced to perform a factory reset on my phone. Lost lots of data. Is there someway to disable the google password lockout (preferable) or another solution that will keep my phone locked and button-mash-proof (preferably without rooting)?

I have a LG Ultimate 2.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There is something I want to clarify. Were you forced to [tag:factory-reset] (not [tag:hard-reset]) because the device was not connected to Wi-Fi or mobile data (internet, in short), during lock-out? If that's the case, why not ask for a way to enable Wi-Fi or mobile data using some secure method?

Comment: @Firelord it is a factory-reset (fixed), and sadly there is not a way to do that, that I am of aware. Spent a lot of time on the web with no success. Anyway I have my phone factory reset, and now I want this not to happen again while still having my phone locked.

Comment: While you've made your point clear already, I still want to suggest this for your consideration: what about sending a particular SMS to activate Wi-Fi and/or mobile data? That can be done easily using [tag:automation]. Or, what about using using custom gesture/swipe to enable Wi-Fi and/or Mobile data? There can be other possibilities that you may have thought but couldn't find an answer for.

Comment: @Firelord I do not want to depend on WiFi or Data being present to login. I want a fully offline way to always have access to my phone.